# Is there an existing solution for pattern recognition?

Tags: model, machine-learning

I've been looking at modeling potential avalanche hazard based on terrain characteristics.  I have a vector layer showing historical avalanche paths and have raster layers for elevation, aspect, slope, curvature and land cover.

I was hoping there was an existing way to use the vector layer to identify what value range from the underlying rasters were present in the known avalanche paths and, perhaps using a bayesian statistical approach, predict/identify new areas that have similar underlying characteristics.

Does a validated GIS model or process already exist to approach this?

Comment: I am currently working on *landslide susceptibility mapping* using GIS & RS data. Most of the papers and thesis I've read;  either used some sort of statistical analysis (bivariate or multivariate regression), AHP (Analytic Hierarchic Process) - easily refutable - or Deep Learning (Artificial Neural Networks).

Comment: you can use a model-based approach, by `extract`ing the values of the raster within a subset of polygons (training data), use this data to build a model ( I don't know the most used model in this field, but for example `randomForests` and `svm` usually provide good results), test the performance of the model on the subset  of polygons left-out  and then `predict` the outcome (it could be the presence/absence of an avalanche or the susceptibility to avalanche) wall-to-wall (also know as spatially explicit prediction) by applying the model to the whole raster variable (elevation, slope, ecc)